# How to make this layout using JFrame

Tags: java, layout, jframe

I'd like to make this layout using JFrame, is it possible ?
[image]

Thank you

Comment: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274)

Comment: `GridBagLayout` for configurability, but you could also use a combination of `GridLayout` and `BorderLayout` - Maybe instead, start with [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) as "I'd like..." is a wish, not a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use border layout as base layout that will hold all components. Add your image to borderlayout.north. Then create 2 flow layout for left and right buttons. Add your buttons to flow layouts and add your layout to left and right of borderlayout.